# use of ";" in a env var on setenv.sh

Tags: java, bash, shell, tomcat

I want to set this environment variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
dburl="jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxxx;user=xxxx@iafox;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Ddburl=${dburl}"
```

But `setenv.sh` don`t identify **";"**, how can I do this?

EDIT

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Ijb.png)

Comment: what error do you receive?

Comment: i put a edit on the post with the image error

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your quesiton.

Comment: I dont see your CATALINA_OPTS having anything to do with that error message.

Comment: i trying to set this env var in my server.xml, if i put out the ; the code compile but without set env

Comment: Depending on how `CATALINA_OPTS` is ultimately used, I can see an issue where the semicolons wind up as statement terminators, rather than as part of the `-D` argument. Try `export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Ddburl=\"$dburl\"` instead. (Ignoring all the other caveats about using a variable to store a space-separate list of arguments for now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that it will help, but you can try this one:

```
dburl="jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxxx;user=xxxx@iafox;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Ddburl='$dburl'"
```